# Как автоматически обновить библиотеку python?

Tags: python

как обновлять библиотеку через `pip` автоматически при запуске скрипта python.
например чтобы `pip install ray` не надо было писать отдельно в консоли.

Comment: Вам это не надо. После обновления код может перестать работать, обратная совместимость не всегда соблюдается. Все обновления надо предварительно тестировать. Но если хотите, можете написать shell скрипт, который сначала обновит библиотеки, а потом уже запустит ваш скрипт на питоне.

Comment: запускать не скрипт питона напрямую, а создать скрипт .sh или .ps1 и там прописать порядок действий перед запуском скрипта и осуществить сам запуск.